# Dynamic Stack layout on button click in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin Project.
I have stacklayout and it contains labels,combox,autocomplete inside it. I want to create a new stacklayout that would contain all the fields on add_button click and delete it on delete_button click.
Here code looks:

```
    StackLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray-100}" Spacing="0" Padding="16,24">
    
                           
              <Label
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}"
                            Margin="0,24,0,4"
                            HeightRequest="18"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Text="Entity *"
                            TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-800}" />
    <Label
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}"
                            Margin="0,24,0,4"
                            HeightRequest="18"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Text="Process *"
                            TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-800}" />

</stacklayout>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know that how I can do that ! I have no idea for that !

Comment: you could use the Button event to set the IsVisible property of your layout to show/hide it.  Or if you really want to build the UI dynamically, you can just construct your layout in code in the Click event

Comment: Actually i wanted to know that how I can a create a another stacklayout on button click  event ? Could you tell me some code of it do that ?

Comment: Suppose I want to delete a stacklayout on button click how to do that ?

Comment: `parentLayout.Children.Remove(element);`

Comment: I have add button on button click i am creating a stacklayout and adding fields inside it label, autocomplete, delete_button and so on.                                                             On delete button click I am trying to remove specific stacklayout but when i click delete it removes all stacklayout.  How can I delete specific layout ? Like loops will work here or anything else ?Could you tell me ?

Comment: pass it a reference to the layout you want to remove

Comment: could you describe in detail ?

Comment: see the edit on my answer

Comment: this things is working fine for me already but let's say I added 100 stacklayout and now suppose i want to delete 80 from it one by one depending upon my choice then this scenario is not working in that case ! I have to implement that part !

Comment: you would need to maintain a reference to the ones you want to remove.  You would probably need to create some sort of data structure for them.  However, if each section is identical it would make more sense to do this with a CollectionView

Comment: could you please show me in this scenario as I am new to Xamarin !

Comment: How are you going to select which layout is deleted?

Comment: if the delete button is inside the StackLayout you want to delete, you can just use `myButton.Parent` to get the StackLayout

Comment: when I will create a new stacklayout a button will be generated as well which is delete button, so for every created new stacklayout we have a delete button. Now it depends upon user which stacklayout he wants to delete !  Right now this code of mine delete button but it is deleting only 1 stacklayout.if I uncomment below lines it deletes all stacklayouts. I need to delete specific ones !

Comment: private void Delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){stack.Children.Remove(label1); stack.Children.Remove(label2);stack.Children.Remove(label3);            stack.Children.Remove(label4); 
            stack.Children.Remove(border1); stack.Children.Remove(border2); stack.Children.Remove(border3);
            stack.Children.Remove(border4); 
            stack.Children.Remove(button);
           // stack.Children.Clear();
           // OuterStack.Children.Remove(stack1);
           //OuterStack.Children.Add(stack1);

        }

Comment: see my edit - if you have more questions, please ask a NEW question instead of continuing to comment on one that has already been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so like this is xaml how would i have to add it in c# exactly. could
> you please tell me ?

You can add the label in c# like:

```
var myLabel = new Label { Text = "This is text.", HeightRequest = 18, FontSize = 12,TextColor= Color.Red };
```

You can read the document about [label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label) and there are code examples both for c# and xaml.

Comment: suppose I don't want these fields to be entered manually. i need exact field already declared in xaml to be a children. How can I code that ?

Comment: Give a name to the label in Xaml like:         `<Label Text="Xamarin.Forms!" x:Name="firstLabel"/>` and then you can get this label in code behind:             `var labelFromXaml = firstLabel;`.

Comment: When I used this command label was removed from outerstack and was added in inner stack. But I want to be both inside as well as outside.

Comment: If you want to keep both, you have to create a new label instead of using the label in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

in your button's click event handler

```
protected void AddStack(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // create UI elements
    var newStack = new StackLayout { ... };
    var label1 = new Label { ... };
    var label2 = new Label { ... };
    var button = new Button { ... };

    button.Clicked += DeleteSection;

    // add to stack
    newStack.Children.Add(label1);
    newStack.Children.Add(label2);

    // add to existing outer layout container
    outerStack.Children.Add(newStack);
}

protected void DeleteSection(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var button = (Button)sender;
  // find the button's parent
  var parent = button.Parent;

  outerstack.Children.Remove(parent);
}
```

Comment: here concern is that inside stacklayout suppose i have 1 label 1 autocomplete 1 combo box and I need exact items of these to be added in another stacklayout so will this command in that case ? Because I need same items again and I can create 100's of stack layouts !

Comment: Yes, just add whatever controls you need to the code.

Comment: var stack = new StackLayout {  what do i need to add here like stacklayout name like that ? };

Comment: names only apply to XAML, in C# you have variable references.  You fill in any properties you want to set in the "{ ... }" just like you would with any C# initializer.

Comment: so like this is xaml how would i have to add it in c# exactly. could you please tell me ? <Label
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}"
                            Margin="0,24,0,4"
                            HeightRequest="18"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Text="Entity *"
                            TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-800}" />

Comment: It is giving me an error "Can't convert from xamarin.forms element to xamarin.forms.view"